# Reemplazar cadenas con replace JS

Tags: javascript, string, str-replace

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo en JS que me detecta en un bloque de contenido si posee alguna de las siguientes secuencias de caracteres y tienen que ser reemplazados por imagenes, el problema es que la funcion replace no me permite reemplazarlos. Aqui esta el codigo:

```
function validarContenido(contenido){
var emoji = [":)","XD",":P",":(",":*","X_X","|**|"];
var icono = ["img/emojis/emoji1.png",
             "img/emojis/emoji2.png",
             "img/emojis/emoji3.png",
             "img/emojis/emoji4.png",
             "img/emojis/emoji5.png",
             "img/emojis/emoji6.png",
             "img/emojis/emoji7.png"];
for(var i=0; i<emoji.length; i++){
    var estaEmoji = contenido.search(emoji[i]);
    console.log(estaEmoji);
    if(estaEmoji!=-1){
        contenido = contenido.replace(emoji[i],icono[i]);
    }
}

console.log(contenido);
return contenido;

}
```

Y el error que me tira es el siguiente:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /:)/: Unmatched ')'
 at String.search (<anonymous>)
 at validarContenido (controlador.js:195)
 at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (controlador.js:151)
 at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
 at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 3):

### Métodos [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) & [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join)

Si no deseas usar [Expresiones Regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) puedes lograr lo que quieres con el **Método del Objeto String [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) & [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join)**

Partiendo de tu codigo te dejo un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

```js
function validarContenido(contenido){
  var emoji = [":)","XD",":P",":(",":*","X_X","|**|"];
  var icono = ["img/emojis/emoji1.png",
               "img/emojis/emoji2.png",
               "img/emojis/emoji3.png",
               "img/emojis/emoji4.png",
               "img/emojis/emoji5.png",
               "img/emojis/emoji6.png",
               "img/emojis/emoji7.png"];

  for(var i=0; i<emoji.length; i++) {
    contenido = contenido.split(emoji[i]).join(icono[i])
  }
  console.log(contenido);
  return contenido;
}
validarContenido(';)')
validarContenido(':)')
validarContenido(":), XD, :P, :(, :*, X_X, |**|, :), XD, :P, :(, :*, X_X, |**|");
```

Answer (score 2):

Probablemente estas buscando el metodo [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)?

El metodo `search` convierte el string como parametro en una expresion regular:

Segun MDN sobre el parametro que recibe:

> Un objeto de expresión regular. Si se pasa un obj de objeto no RegExp,
>   se convierte implícitamente a RegExp utilizando el nuevo RegExp (obj).

De ahi que te lanze el error. Intenta utilizando `indexOf` que retorna -1 si no se encuentra el `string` indicado:

```js
    function validarContenido(contenido){
    var emoji = [":)","XD",":P",":(",":*","X_X","|**|"];
    var icono = ["img/emojis/emoji1.png",
                 "img/emojis/emoji2.png",
                 "img/emojis/emoji3.png",
                 "img/emojis/emoji4.png",
                 "img/emojis/emoji5.png",
                 "img/emojis/emoji6.png",
                 "img/emojis/emoji7.png"];
    for(var i=0; i<emoji.length; i++){
        var estaEmoji = contenido.indexOf(emoji[i]);
        
        if(estaEmoji!=-1){
            contenido = contenido.replace(emoji[i],icono[i]);
        }
    }

    console.log(contenido);
    return contenido;

    }

    validarContenido(':)')
```

Comment: Okay lo intentare, gracias

Answer (score -1):

La función [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/search) usa [expresiones regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), y `:)` no es una expresión regular válida.

Si quieres buscar un emoji como `':)'` tendrás que escapar los caracteres especiales (en este caso el paréntesis):

```js
let texto= 'esto es un emoji -> :)';

let emoji=/:\)/; // usando comillas sería ":\\)"

console.log('Lo encontramos a partir de la posición',texto.search(emoji));
```

Comment: No me soluciona el problema, pero buscando mas fondo encontre que para escapar correctamente el emoji seria :\\\)

Comment: Todo depende de si escribes una regex como un string o no: fíjate que yo he usado / como delimitador